# Alter table add column and set default value using the table records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Is there a way to add a new column and set its default value comming from the table in MySQL?

for example i have this table "sampleTable"

```
ID|    column_text|    content
1 |           bla1|     sadas|
2 |           bla2|     sadas|
3 |           bla3|     sadas|
4 |           bla4|     sadas|
```

then i want to execute a command that add a column and use the default value column_text.

`ALTER TABLE sampleTableADD  column_text_duplicate longtext DEFAULT *comming from column_text;`

Comment: Is this a one-off process or are you going to be adding columns a lot to this table

Comment: If its a one-off then just alter the table and do a simple update query

Comment: well i have so many records in the actual table so yeah i need a sample query or script @RiggsFolly

Comment: This seems like a dodgy solution to something  - why would you want to do this?

Comment: for hacking purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So alter the table and then run a simple update query.

```
ALTER TABLE sampleTableADD  column_text_duplicate longtext;
UPDATE sampleTableADD SET column_text_duplicate = column_text;
```

But this seems a little unnecessary, why would you want 2 columns containing the same data. I assume you must then be amending the copy column in at least some of the rows!